# Insert using IF/ELSE statements

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I am sorry if my question is not clear or my query is not sufficient to help. I have a procedure that has multiple if/else statement. My goal is to insert one row if that if statements meets the criteria else go further. Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure abc.xyz
       ( i_name    varchar2
        ,number    number,
         sections       varchar2)
      ...
    max_date date;
    min_date   date;
     ...
    if(sum=0)
    insert into abc_table
    (id,name,number,sections,description,date,amount,price,source,latest_date)
     select user_seq.nextval,name,number,max_date,amount,0 
     ,'xyz',trunc(sysdate))
      from abc_table x
      where x.name=i_name
      and x.number=i_name
     and x.section=i_section;

    elseif (sum>0)
     insert into abc_table
     (id,name,number,sections,description,date,amount,price,source,latest_date)
     select user_seq.nextval,name,number,max_date,amount,0 
     ,'xyz',trunc(sysdate))
      from abc_table x
      where x.name=i_name
      and x.number=i_name;
      and x.section=i_section;
```

when i run my procedure, to insert the calculated value , the values are correct but so many rows were inserted. How can I prevent from multiple insert and make only one row insert ?

Comment: How do you determine which record gets inserted?

Comment: i want to insert from select statement and id is created by seq.nextval

Comment: i was able to insert but so many got inserted instead of one row.

Comment: You need to INSERT using a SELECT clause that selects only one row. If nothing else you can always include `WHERE RowNum = 1`.

Comment: @kkl Did you first check if the query used in you if clause is actually returning a single row. What do you get when you execute `select user_seq.nextval,name,number,max_date,amount,0 
     ,'xyz',trunc(sysdate))
      from abc_table x
      where x.name=i_name
      and x.number=i_name
     and x.section=i_section` where you replace all the variables with the actual values. Are you getting 1 record in all the cases ? Apart, i can see the `IF ELSIF-IF` syntax is wrong in the above code you posted, so my next question is `if actually you code working ?`

Comment: @JohnWu..Where RowNum=1 works for me ..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

According to the Oracle documentation, The syntax for the Oracle INSERT statement when inserting a single record using the VALUES keyword is:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... column_n )
VALUES
(expression1, expression2, ... expression_n );
```

But the syntax for the Oracle INSERT statement when inserting multiple records using a SELECT statement is:

```
INSERT INTO table
(column1, column2, ... column_n )
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM source_table
[WHERE conditions];
```

reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php

from the link i shared: 
If you don't want to insert duplicate:

```
INSERT INTO clients
(client_id, client_name, client_type)
SELECT 10345, 'IBM', 'advertising'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM clients
              WHERE clients.client_id = 10345);
```